# Juliabox cannot be launched

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

Today when I was trying to use JuliaBox on my browser, I found that I cannot even launch it. (Please see the picture below). Every button on the page is not clickable. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

[No button can be clicked on my Juliabox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8k1cr.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is on the home page of juliabox.com; unfortunately it's no longer possible to provide it as a free resource.  For more details and support, you can contact Julia Computing directly.

> NOTE: As of Nov 1, 2019, the free version of JuliaBox is no longer available.
>
> Register today to become a paid subscriber, starting at just $7 per month for academic users, or $14 per month for non-academic users.

[image: Juliabox.com homepage]